# C# Sorting error while using IComparable

Tags: c#, sorting, arraylist, icomparable

I'm trying for hours to sort an ArrayList using IComparable...

Please note that I cant use IComparer to do this.

Here is the code :

```
class Pays : IComparable<Pays>
{
    private string nomPays;

    public string NomPays{get{return nomPays;}set{nomPays = value;}}

    public int CompareTo(object x)
    {
        Pays myX = (Pays)x;
        return string.Compare(this.nomPays, x.nomPays);
    }
}

class TestPays
{
    public static ArrayList LireRemplirPays(){ //...blabla
        return uneListe;
    }
    static void Main(string[] args){
        ArrayList paysList = LireRemplirPays();
        paysList.Sort();          
    }
}
```

Error paste :
System.ArgumentException: At least one object must implement IComparable
System.Collections.Comparer.Compare(Object a, Object b)......

What can I do ? thanks for reading

Edit :

So my first mistake was :

```
class Pays : IComparable<Pays>
```

instead of

```
class Pays : IComparable
```

second mistake :

```
return nomPays.CompareTo(myX.nomPays);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use a generic list instead of an `ArrayList`:

```
class TestPays
{
    public static List<Pays> LireRemplirPays() { //...blabla
        return uneListe; // Cast here if necessary
    }
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        List<Pays> paysList = LireRemplirPays();
        paysList.Sort();          
    }
}
```

`ArrayList` isn't generic and could contain any type of object, and `object` doesn't implement `IComparable`.

Also, if `NomPays` doesn't actually do any checking, you can use the shorthand and not have to explicitly declare a backing field:

```
public string Nom { get; set; }
```